# error: Sharp is required to be installed in standalone mode for image optimization

Tags: docker, npm, image-processing, next.js, nrwl-nx

Dockerfile:

```
# Build Image - Stage 1
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# Stage 2 - Install Dependencies
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat vips-dev python3 make g++

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* .npmrc ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

# Stage 3 - Build Application
# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
RUN npm run build:projectx-ui

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

USER nextjs

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/dist/apps/projectx-ui/public ./apps/projectx-ui/public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/dist/apps/projectx-ui/.next/standalone/ ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/dist/apps/projectx-ui/.next/static ./dist/apps/projectx-ui/.next/static

# Expose port 4000 for the application
EXPOSE 4000

# Add the port as 
ENV PORT 4000

# Start the application
# CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--port", "4000"]
CMD ["node", "apps/projectx-ui/server.js"]
```

I am using the NX monorepo tool. The Dockerfile is added to the root. I have installed sharp. I went through several GitHub issues but none of the solutions worked. I have also tried setting the environment variable as mentioned in the Nextjs doc. But, it didn't work.

Whenever I start the server from the docker image and open the URL on my local machine, I see the error `error: Sharp is required to be installed in standalone mode for image optimization

I can see that the module is available as `sharp-linuxmusl-arm64v8.node`

I see the same error when I deploy the app. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production)

Comment: @codeaprendiz Yes!

Comment: Looks like it should be added as production dependency. How about logging into the actual container and checking if you can find it there? also the ENV they are talking about NEXT_SHARP_PATH might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/app/node_modules/sharp`
in your Dockerfile after `ENV NODE_ENV production`.

The docs say to add `ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp` but if you check where the modules are in your container you'll see they are in `/app`.